# Is there a way to get all recipients in `to` or `cc` fields?

Tags: outlook-web-addins

It is mentioned in documentation of `Office.MessageRead.to` that:

> The to property returns an array that contains an EmailAddressDetails object for each recipient listed on the To line of the message. The collection is limited to a maximum of 100 members.

This limitation is working correctly, if I have an message which was sent to more than 100 recipients, I can only get 100 of email addresses with `Office.context.mailbox.item.to`.

No similar limitation is mentioned in documentation of `Office.AppointmentRead.requiredAttendees`, but I can only get 100 of email addresses with `Office.context.mailbox.item.requiredAttendees`.

**Question**

I've tried to get recipients with both `Office.context.mailbox.item.to` and [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/use-rest-api), I can only get 100 email addresses. **Is there a way to get a complete list of recipients?**

Comment: Digging into this a bit more, the limit to this should be 500 recipients, but this may depend on the client that you are on. For Win32 Outlook 2016 (and after) this should be 500 recipients. Can you provide more information about the client that you are on?

Comment: I was working with Microsoft Outlook for Mac Version 16.31 (19101400) (Office Insider Fast).
macOS Mojave 10.14.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to use the [GetItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/getitem-operation) method available in EWS.

See [Exchange Online Throttling and Limits FAQ](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2011/06/23/exchange-online-throttling-and-limits-faq/) for more information about limits in Exchange.

Comment: Thanks. What you suggested works: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/web-services

However it requires `ReadWriteMailbox ` permission to use `makeEwsRequestAsync` API, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/understanding-outlook-add-in-permissions#readwritemailbox-permission

Comment: Eugene's answer is correct. There is no way around this limitation aside through EWS. For feature requests please add these to our uservoice: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins

Comment: Thanks, feature requested: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/38779018-do-not-require-readwritemailbox-permission-to-ca

Answer (score 0):

Eugene's answer suggested to use `Office.context.mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync` to send SOAP XML requests for retrieving full list of recipients. It works if you have specified [`ReadWriteMailbox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/understanding-outlook-add-in-permissions) permission in Office add-in manifest.

```xml
<Permissions>ReadWriteMailbox</Permissions>
```

Code example for making use of `Office.context.mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync`:

```js
/**
 * @param {HTMLElement} node The `t:Mailbox` node. As in
 * <t:Mailbox>
 *  <t:Name>At The Table</t:Name>
 *  <t:EmailAddress>atthetable@microstrategy.com</t:EmailAddress>
 *  <t:RoutingType>SMTP</t:RoutingType>
 *  <t:MailboxType>Mailbox</t:MailboxType>
 * </t:Mailbox>
 * @return {string} A string as in `Name (email@address.com)` when success;
 * empty string otherwise.
 */
const parseMailboxNode = (node) => {
  const nameNode = node.getElementsByTagName('t:Name')[0];
  const addressNode = node.getElementsByTagName('t:EmailAddress')[0];
  return {
    displayName: nameNode.textContent,
    emailAddress: addressNode.textContent,
  };
};

const parseEmailAddresses = (doc, messageFieldName) => {
  const fieldNode = doc.getElementsByTagName(`t:${messageFieldName}`)[0];
  if (!fieldNode) {
    return [];
  }

  const emailAddresses = [];
  const mailboxes = fieldNode.getElementsByTagName('t:Mailbox');
  for (let i = 0, l = mailboxes.length; i < l; i += 1) {
    emailAddresses.push(parseMailboxNode(mailboxes[i]));
  }
  return emailAddresses;
};

const parseGetItemSoapResponse = (xml) => {
  try {
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLDocument
    const doc = parser.parseFromString(xml, 'application/xml');
    const message = {
      ReplyTo: parseEmailAddresses(doc, 'ReplyTo')[0],
    };
    return [
      'ToRecipients',
      'CcRecipients',
      'BccRecipients',
      'RequiredAttendees',
      'OptionalAttendees',
    ].reduce((result, fieldName) => {
      result[fieldName] = parseEmailAddresses(doc, fieldName);
      return result;
    }, message);
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error('Failed to parse XML response of Office.context.mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync', xml);
    return null;
  }
};

const getRecipients = async (item) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const { context } = window.Office || {};
  const { mailbox } = context || {};
  if (!mailbox || !mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync) {
    const error = new Error('Office.context.mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync is not available.');
    reject(error);
    return;
  }

  const { itemId } = item || {};
  if (!itemId) {
    const error = new Error('Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId is invalid.');
    reject(error);
    return;
  }

  // See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/web-services
  // See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/getitem-operation-email-message
  // See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/fielduri
  const request = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:xsd="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
  <soap:Header>
    <RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" soap:mustUnderstand="0" />
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <GetItem xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
      <ItemShape>
        <t:BaseShape>IdOnly</t:BaseShape>
        <t:AdditionalProperties>
            <t:FieldURI FieldURI="message:ReplyTo"/>
            <t:FieldURI FieldURI="message:ToRecipients"/>
            <t:FieldURI FieldURI="message:CcRecipients"/>
            <t:FieldURI FieldURI="message:BccRecipients"/>
            <t:FieldURI FieldURI="calendar:RequiredAttendees"/>
            <t:FieldURI FieldURI="calendar:OptionalAttendees"/>
        </t:AdditionalProperties>
      </ItemShape>
      <ItemIds><t:ItemId Id="${itemId}"/></ItemIds>
    </GetItem>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
`;

  mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync(request, (result) => {
    if (result.error) {
      reject(result.error);
    } else {
      const value = parseGetItemSoapResponse(result.value);
      resolve(value);
    }
  });
});
```